# Using substring function in C# gives ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I extract the value 2 from a `string pid = {id=2}`.

My code looks like

```
string pidnew= pid.Substring(3,5)
```

It's showing me error, have I made anything wrong?

Comment: second argument (length) should be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get individual values out of a string like `string pid = "{id=2, genderid=5, stateid=4}"`, you could use this method:

```
public string GetValue(string idPart, string test)
{
    var escIdPart = Regex.Escape(idPart);
    var pattern = string.Format("(?<=[\\{{\\s,]{0}\\s*=\\s*)\\d+", escIdPart);
    var result = default(string);
    var match = Regex.Match(test, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        result = match.Value;
    }
    return result;
}

...

var pid = "{id=2, genderid=5, stateid=4}";

var id = GetValue("id", pid); // returns "2"
var genderid = GetValue("genderid", pid); // returns "5"
var stateid = GetValue("stateid", pid); // returns "4"
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the values as 4 , is there any way that i could get 4 using anyohter function so that I can use globally

Comment: I've updated my answer to give the ability to pick any value out of the string you specified in your comment to the accepted answer, without hardcoding anything.

Answer (score 1):

if there's only one number you can just Regex it

```
string pidnew = Regex.Match(pid, @"\d+").Value;
```

and you won't need to worry about the location

if you want to match on stateid:

```
string pidnew = Regex.Match(pid, @"(?<=stateid=)\d+",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

Comment: if more numbers are there in a string like say for eample string pid={id=2, genderid=5,stateid=4}. then how to get Stateid alone from th string

Comment: Didnot work for me when multiple integers where there in a string example string pid={ selectedid = 9, genderid=1} how to get genderid I did like  but its giving me null value 

    string pidnew = Regex.Match(pid, @"(?<=genderid=)\d+",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for `Substring` tells the number of characters to take. Thus if you have the string "{id=2}" and perform `string pidnew= pid.Substring(3,5)`, what you're saying is: "Start at the character index 3 in the string (fourth character), and take five characters". This means the string would need to be at least 8 characters long. Since you only want to take one character, change the second parameter to a 1. You should also start at index 4 rather than 3 if the brackets are part of your string.

What you actually need is: `string pidnew= pid.Substring(4,1);`

[MSDN Docs:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

> Parameters
>
> startIndex
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.
>
> length
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The number of characters in the substring.