# Extract specific number from string with fixed pattern in C#

Tags: c#, string

This might sound like a very basic question, but it's one that's given me quite a lot of trouble in `C#`.

Assume I have, for example, the following `String`s known as my `chosenTarget.title`s:

```
2008/SD128934 - Wordz aaaaand more words (1233-26-21)
20998/AD1234 - Wordz and less words (1263-21-21)
208/ASD12345 - Wordz and more words (1833-21-21)
```

Now as you can see, all three `String`s are different in some ways.

What I need is to extract a very specific part of these `String`s, but getting the subtleties right is what confuses me, and I was wondering if some of you knew better than I.

What I know is that the `String`s will always come in the following pattern:

`yearNumber + "/" + aFewLetters + theDesiredNumber + " - " + descriptiveText + " (" + someDate + ")"`

In the above example, what I would want to return to me would be:

```
128934
1234
12345
```

I need to extract `theDesiredNumber`.

Now, I'm not (that) lazy so I have made a few attempts myself:

```
var a = chosenTarget.title.Substring(chosenTarget.title.IndexOf("/") + 1, chosenTarget.title.Length - chosenTarget.title.IndexOf("/"));
```

What this has done is sliced out `yearNumber` and the `/`, leaving me with `aFewLetter` before `theDesiredNumber`.

I have a hard time properly removing the rest however, and I was wondering if any of you could aid me in the matter?

Comment: What years are `208` and `20998`? Really 208 and 20998?

Comment: Heh, I just made those `String`s up to suit the example. I think what I copied in was `2008` and I just added and removed number for variety and to demonstrate that I don't know the length of the year beforehand.

Comment: for such case, Regex solution might be best

Comment: I would prefer regex. Try this one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841883/regular-expressions-c-sharp-is-it-possible-to-extract-matches-while-matching and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410065/using-regex-in-c-net-to-extract-data-from-a-string

Comment: Avoid Regex. WAY overkill. From what you currently have, just find the first index for which `char.IsDigit` returns true, and add another `Substring`.

Comment: `\d+\/[a-zA-Z]+(\d+) -` (http://regexr.com/3cqug) for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as if you only need to extract the number behind the first `/` which ends at `-`. You could use a combination of string methods and LINQ:

```
int startIndex = str.IndexOf("/");
string number = null;
if (startIndex >= 0 )
{
    int endIndex = str.IndexOf(" - ", startIndex);
    if (endIndex >= 0)
    {
        startIndex++;
        string token = str.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex); // SD128934
        number = String.Concat(token.Where(char.IsDigit)); // 128934
    }
}
```

Another mainly LINQ approach using `String.Split`:

```
number = String.Concat(
            str.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]
              .Split('/')
              .Last()
              .Where(char.IsDigit));
```

Comment: Good answers all around, but considering I don't know much about Regex (which I will be researching more now!) and Tim kept the answer within my limited understanding so point goes to him.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 int indexSlash = chosenTarget.title.IndexOf("/");
 int indexDash = chosenTarget.title.IndexOf("-");
 string out = new string(chosenTarget.title.Substring(indexSlash,indexDash-indexSlash).Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
var pattern = "(?:[0-9]+/\w+)[0-9]";
var matcher = new Regex(pattern);
var result = matcher.Matches(yourEntireSetOfLinesInAString);
```

Or you can loop every line and use Match instead of Matches. In this case you don't need to build a "matcher" in every iteration but build it outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Regex is your friend:

```
(new [] {"2008/SD128934 - Wordz aaaaand more words (1233-26-21)",
"20998/AD1234 - Wordz and less words (1263-21-21)",
"208/ASD12345 - Wordz and more words (1833-21-21)"})
.Select(x => new Regex(@"\d+/[A-Z]+(\d+)").Match(x).Groups[1].Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you had recognized is very important, here is the solution:

```
const string pattern = @"\d+\/[a-zA-Z]+(\d+).*$";
string s1 = @"2008/SD128934 - Wordz aaaaand more words(1233-26-21)";
string s2 = @"20998/AD1234 - Wordz and less words(1263-21-21)";
string s3 = @"208/ASD12345 - Wordz and more words(1833-21-21)";
var strings = new List<string> { s1, s2, s3 };
var desiredNumber = string.Empty;

foreach (var s in strings)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        desiredNumber = match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a RegEx for this, the string you're looking for is in Match.Groups[1]

```
        string composite = "2008/SD128934 - Wordz aaaaand more words (1233-26-21)";
        Match m= Regex.Match(composite,@"^\d{4}\/[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)");
        if (m.Success) Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
```

The breakdown of the RegEx is as follows

```
"^\d{4}\/[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)"

^           - Indicates that it's the beginning of the string
\d{4}       - Four digits
\/          - /
[a-zA-Z]+   - More than one letters
(\d+)       - More than one digits (the parenthesis indicate that this part is captured as a group - in this case group 1)
```